# Lambda `AssumeRole` as Cognito Identity when authenticated using IAM on API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I have set up API Gateway to be authenticated using IAM, I love the idea of the user getting temporary credentials which they can then use to access services. This setup also helps to configure endpoints that are accessible to both authenticated and unauthenticated users.

The promise (in my mind, at least) is that we can access all services using these temporary credentials (or equivalent tokens).

The limitation I seem to have found is with lamdas that are executed from API Gateway. While there are parameters in the "event" that tell me that the user has been authenticated, I cannot find a way to `AssumeRole` as the Cognito Identity authenticated against the API Gateway.

I have tried to use `STS` to `AssumeRole` as the role defined as the authenticated user defined in the `CognitoIdentityPool`.

`AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` feels like a better fit, but in the plethora of fields passed into the lambda, I am not sure there is a `WebIdentityToken`.

So far, I have been using the HTTP API Gateway. I see that the REST Endpoint within API Gateway can use Cognito Authoriser. From what I can tell, this would not allow unauthenticated/guest users through Cognito Identity Pools.

I can see that with AWS Amplify and the temporary IAM credentials, the client could access the services directly, which would work for the most part. However, I would like to provide a simplified backend to keep the client lighter.

Is it possible to have one of the possible outcomes?

- Have the lambda executed as the Cognito Identity IAM role
- Within the lambda, assume the Cognito Identity IAM role. Is there some token here that I am missing?

I am loathed to give lambda access to whole S3 buckets or DynamoDB tables and would prefer to set user-level policies, which I can apply only if I can assume the role of that identity.

Any pointers, guidance and help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you granting the temporary credentials in the client? Through identity pool? If so, what identity provider?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are configuring the IAM role in Cognito groups, so that you can assign different groups with different permissions.

There are 2 options I can think of to achieve what you want.

#### Option 1

1. The IAM role will have a section called Trust Policy to allow Cognito to assume that role. You have to modify this to allow Lambda to also assume the role.
2. In the Lambda execution role, ensure that it also has permission to allow Lambda to assume that other role.
3. In the Lambda code, the API to call should be `AssumeRole` (instead of the other variations like `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`).

#### Option 2

Since IAM roles control access to AWS services, you can have the client side call the AWS APIs directly, instead of fronting everything using a Lambda.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

Option 1 sadly won't work since it's not group - it's per-user access to DynamoDB that we're looking for. 

Option 2 is tricky since the client is a flutter app, and adding in AWS Amplify for what is a single REST endpoint feels like a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Hence, the desire to AssumeRole within Lambda

Sounds like I might be **** out of luck! :(